# Error loading command module azure ml when setup azure ml

Tags: azure

I tried to set up my Azure Machine Learning environment on Linux(Ubuntu) data science virtual machine on Azure with this command line:

`az ml env setup`

However, it shows an error as an error loading command module `ml`. Been googling about this issue but seems like no one has this issue before.

I can't even see the options by typing:

`az ml -h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to run this command it seems is from the:

File > Open Command Prompt

menu item within the desktop software called:

Azure Machine Learning Workbench

The ml option is not available in Azure Cloud Shell or Powershell desktop.